# how much current does plasma speaker needs?

Tags: electricity, acoustics, plasma-physics

I want to build a plasma speaker,I know they need very high voltage,but what about current? For example electrostatic speakers need high voltage too but low current.

I wonder how much Watts/Volts/Amps will I need to move enough air to get loudness and freqency extension in the bass comparable to conventional moving coil loudspeakers,I know this is very variable depending if its dipole or horn,distance,listening room size etc... I just want a "ballpark" estimate to roughly imagine what kind of power would it take.

Another question,which gas would be most efficient for plasma speaker? Could it be more efficient if it was created in Helium or Argon instead of air?

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but in this paper where they are analyzing properties of the arc they display two instances of arcs carrying rms currents of around 10-30mA. https://mcs-notes2.open.ac.uk/802574C70048F266/(httpAssets)/B6D23D0611CDC89D8025796500418867/$file/paper68.pdf
This paper is also interesting as a general review of plasma speakers: http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2013/WCE2013_pp1111-1116.pdf

Comment: a sandwich  Thank you so much! The first link especialy was helpfull